# Listview binding works with shared runtime but not when it's disabled (Xamarin Forms / Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView that gets data bound from a DataTable. It works and shows the data when I have "Shared Runtime" enabled. When that's disabled the data doesn't appear.

```
 DataTable DataTableContactList = new DataTable();
                DataTableContactList.Columns.Add("AccountId");
                DataTableContactList.Columns.Add("Username");

                foreach (Contact c in encryptedContactList.Contact)
                {
                    DataRow row = DataTableContactList.NewRow();
                    row["AccountId"] = Security.DecryptStringAES(c.encryptedContactAccountId, Utility.Prefs.Get("guid"));
                    row["Username"] = Security.DecryptStringAES(c.encryptedContactUsername, Utility.Prefs.Get("guid"));
                    //await DisplayAlert("Alert", "row['Username']: " + row["Username"].ToString(), "", "ok");
                    DataTableContactList.Rows.Add(row);

                }

                ListViewContactList.ItemsSource = DataTableContactList.DefaultView;
                ListViewContactList.EndRefresh();
                lblNoContacts.IsVisible = false;
```

[image: screenshot with data displaying correctly]
[image: screenshot where data doesn't display]

Comment: Hi , remember to mark the answer when you have time , it will help others who have similar issue. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was changing ".Android>Android Options>Linker properties>Linking" to "None". I tried both "Sdk Assemblies Only" and "Sdk and User Assemblies" but neither of them worked for me. Now I don't understand why this worked, and I hope I haven't caused some other component to stop working. If anyone has extra input on this, I would appreciate it. As far as I can tell I still have all the functionality I need, so I'll just continue forward without question.... for now...